# Extract number when still attached to string

Tags: python, regex, match

I want to extract German mobile numbers. My Python regex works very well. There is only one exception which I don't know how to catch.

My regex:

```
\+491\d{9,10}\b
```

How can I extract the number if a sting is attached to it?:

```
Germany  +4915255687865Total SMS: 6758
```

Please see full example in my demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/mZbuAs/1).

Comment: Use `(?!\d)` instead of `\b`, `\+491\d{9,10}(?!\d)`. `\b` after `\d` pattern requires either end of string or a char other than letter, digit or `_` to follow immediately.